# Getting rid of the error about the loss of content when updating was files in WildFly (or Jboss EAP) forever

Tags: jboss, wildfly8, wildfly

It is not a trivial question about an error on WildFly(10):

> WFLYSRV0137: No deployment content with hash
>   edba0011304daa1b2648eb4848a44536acbbebf6 is available in the
>   deployment content repository for deployment 'ANYDEPLOYMENT'. This is a fatal
>   boot error. To correct the problem, either restart with the
>   --admin-only switch set and use the CLI to install the missing content or remove it from the configuration, or remove the deployment from the
>   xml configuration file and restart.

Google has a lot of information on manually editing such an error, and it consists in simply deleting the entry in standalone.xml / domain.xml manually and restarting the server.

Root Cause is everywhere indicated as:

> "The error usually occurs when standalone / data or domain / data
>   directories are deleted and then an attempt to redeploy the same
>   application war file. The WildFly server is unable to delete entries
>   defined in standalone.xml / domain.xml with the same hash for the
>   deployed application"

For Jboss EAP, the same is true for the redhat portal: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1370523

But explain how to get rid of this problem in the bud? And do not constantly edit the file manually.
There is no solution anywhere, but this problem arises quite often when updating war files.

In fact, I am not sure of the correctness of this reason, since I have a problem with the following algorithm:

1. WildFly works as usual
2. CLI: Delete the old war / Install the new one (with a new hash). There are no errors and everything works
3. Restarting WildFly after a while. When restarting, this error occurs.

If look at standalone.xml, i can see that the hash is from the new war, but the content itself is not in standalone/data.

What measures can be taken to get rid of this error forever with redeploy? And do not fix it manually every fifth installation and restart of the WildFly server.

And I hope there are solutions without actions that require restarting WildFly...

Answer (score 0):

First you may want to upgrade WildFly as several errors were fixed.
The bud of the issue is desynchronization between WildFly configuration and the deployment content repository. That's why any manipulation of the data folder may create this.